# Set up X ticks on Grid with np.arange() which always show the "0" on the axis

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, charts

I have a little issue and just can't figure it out how to do it.
The problem is I have a chart where I have a minimum and a maximum value from two list and stored only one value:

```
datamax = []
datamin = []
```

All this value is an integer.
The `datamin` is always a negative number. Using the following code to set up the ticks for the X axis.

```
chrtXticks = np.arange(datamin, datamax, 20)
```

The problem is I always want to have the "0" on my X axis.
I tried to change the value of my `datamax` and `datamin` with the following if statement but it's not working:

```
if datamax <= 60:
    datamax = 80
else:
     if datamax > 60:
         datamax = 120
     else:
         if datamax > 120:
             datamax = 220
         else:
             if datamax > 220:
                datamax = 320
             else:
                 if datamax > 320:
                    datamax = 420
```

I'm sure there is a better way.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the bounds this way:

```
datamax=(datamax//20+1)*20+1
datamin=(datamin//20)*20
```

if you want to use an arbitrary resolution:

```
chrtXticks = np.arange((datamin//res)*res, (datamax//res+1)*res+1, res)
```

Reasoning:

Integer division rounds to lower value, so while `47//10=4`, `-47//10=-5`.  Thus positive values need +1 before multiplying

Adding +1 to the maxvalue allows the max value to be included in `np.arange` (which would otherwise truncate it)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your if's wont work, is you will never reach the end.
if datamax is greater than 60, datamax = 120, and thats it, it wont get further even if datamax is greater than 320.

Try writing your if statements like this:

```
if datamax <= 60:
    datamax = 80
elif datamax > 320:
    datamax = 420
elif datamax > 220:
    datamax = 320
elif datamax > 120:
    datamax = 220
elif datamax > 60:
    datamax = 120
```

Comment: Hi EL3PHANTEN I tried this but did not worked for me for some reason. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @user7540763 No problem, I was not sure it was going to solve your actual problem eiter, just pointing out the problem in your if's :)